# change data frame so thousands are separated by dots

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, decimal

At the moment, I'm working with RMarkdown and Pandoc. My data.frames in R look like this:

```
3.538e+01 3.542e+01 3.540e+01
9.583e+00 9.406e+00 9.494e+00
2.601e+05 2.712e+05 5.313e+05
```

After I ran pandoc, the result looks like this:

```
35.380 35.420 35.400
9.583 9.406 9.494
260116.000 271217.000 531333.000
```

What it should look like is:

```
35,380 35,420 35,400
9,583  9,406  9,494
260.116 271.217 531.333
```

So I want commas instead of dots and I want no comma or dot after 260116 (thousand numbers). The dots to separate the thousand would be nice. Is there a way to directly Change the appearance in R or do I have to set options in knitr/markdown?

Thanks

Comment: and e.g 3720651 should be represented as 3.720.651

Comment: See `format` and `sprintf` perhaps.

Comment: You should probably show your code...since it's not really clear what procedure you're performing on what input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of some of the conversions that can be done with `format()`:

```
x <- c(35.38, 35.42, 35.4, 9.583, 9.406, 9.494, 260100, 271200, 531300)
format(x, decimal.mark=",", big.mark=".", scientific=FALSE)
# [1] "     35,380" "     35,420" "     35,400" "      9,583" "      9,406"
# [6] "      9,494" "260.100,000" "271.200,000" "531.300,000"
```

There are several other options, such as `trim`, `justify`, and so on that might be of interest in getting your output ready for pandoc.

Comment: just one thing, how can I delete the three NULL?

Comment: @beginneR, please take some time to read `?format` and the linked help pages. You'll run across a *wide range* of arguments to control the formatting of the output, one of which is the logical `drop0trailing` which should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As this question was really inspiring, I [recently](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/76b10c92f4a57d6e0e9a1e983486ae0959084dc0) introduced that `big.mark` feature in my pander package, that can return markdown formatted tables from R objects with predefined options -- building on `format` by the way. Small demo:

1. Load the package ([installed from GH](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation) until this features gets to CRAN):

   ```
   > library(pander)
   ```
2. Create a demo `data.frame`:

   ```
   > x <- matrix(c(35.38, 35.42, 35.4, 9.583, 9.406, 9.494, 260100, 271200, 531300), 3, byrow = TRUE)
   ```
3. Set your default options: (values for US context may need to be switched)

   ```
   > panderOptions('decimal.mark', ',')
   > panderOptions('big.mark', '.')
   ```
4. Let `pander` do the rest:

   ```
   > pander(x)

   ------- ------- -------
    35,38   35,42   35,4  

    9,583   9,406   9,494 

   260.100 271.200 531.300
   ------- ------- -------
   ```

You can find and use even more options there (like the markdown syntax for the table).

Comment: Very nice addition to pander! +1

Comment: Thank you very much @AnandaMahto, it's always a pleasure to hear such great feedback :)

Comment: for US context, consider the reverse marks: panderOptions('big.mark', ',')